# Opening curly brace at a newline in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Based on [Kotlin coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#formatting), it is discouraged to put opening curly braces on its own line as semi-colons are optional and that might cause surprising behavior. What would the surprising behavior be if we put the opening brace on its own line?

---

> ### Formatting
>
> In most cases, Kotlin follows the Java coding conventions.
>
> Use 4 spaces for indentation. Do not use tabs.
>
> For curly braces, put the opening brace in the end of the line where
>   the construct begins, and the closing brace on a separate line aligned
>   horizontally with the opening construct.
>
> ```
> if (elements != null) {
>     for (element in elements) {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> (Note: In Kotlin, semicolons are optional, and therefore line breaks are significant. The language design assumes Java-style braces,
>   and **you may encounter surprising behavior** if you try to use a
>   different formatting style.)

Comment: See this: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-forces-open-brace-style-in-some-situations/1425. Essentially, (it seems) it'll never mistake block for lambda, but it can do the reverse.

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/sam-style-curly-brace-quirk/2385

Comment: ASI can be an occasional pain.

Comment: Is there any reason I can't have my method declarations put the opening brace on a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment about surprising behavior is not about the curly brace, but more general. Consider this code:

```
val result = 1
+ 2
println(result)
```

you might expect this to print "3", but it prints "1" because these are 2 statements, `val result = 1` and `+ 2`

You would write it like this in Kotlin if you wanted to break the line:

```
val result = 1 +
2
```

this is a simple example, but highlights the difference that not having semicolons to determine the end of a statement makes.

Comment: Not sure this answers the original question which was about the implications of opening a brace on a newline.